# Adding and removing values from array by checking and unchecking checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code adds checkbox values to an array when checkboxes are checked.  How can I change this so that a checkbox's value is removed from the array when a checkbox is unchecked?

```
var departments = [];
$("input[name='department_pk[]']").change(function() {
        $("input[name='department_pk[]']:checked").each(function(i){
          departments[i] = $(this).val();
        }); 
});
```

Comment: do you really need .each method here?? because when you tick as example one of the checkbox, it will trigger this code. And you can use push function to add the value and splice it using .splice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are not removing the previously selected items from the array. Assume you have selected 5 items now in the array you have data for indexes 0 to 4, then you are unselecting 2 items now your each loop will reset the indexes 0 to 2 but the indexes 3 and 4 is still present in the array. that is the problem.

A better solution will be is to create a fresh array using [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var departments = [];
$("input[name='department_pk[]']").change(function () {
    departments = $("input[name='department_pk[]']:checked").map(function (i) {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this...I didn't know about the map()...so I have learned something!

Answer (score 0):

I would clear the array first before you add new elements to it.

```
var departments = [];
$("input[name='department_pk[]']").change(function() {
    departments = [];
    $("input[name='department_pk[]']:checked").each(function(i){
      departments[i] = $(this).val();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
check this..
var departments = [];
    $("input[name='department_pk[]']").change(function() {
            $("input[name='department_pk[]']").each(function(i){
              if(jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
                 departments[i] = $(this).val();
               } else {
                  departments[i] = 0;
               }
            }); 
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

This sort of worked, but map() is more accurate:

```
          if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    departments.push($(this).val());
  } else {
    departments.pop($(this).val());
  }
```

Comment: The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns that element.